# Is it typical to have 499 and 502 HTTP errors in real applications?

Tags: python, nginx, optimization, flask, uwsgi

I'm involved in optimizing a Flask web application deployed using uWSGI through NGINX reverse proxy. The response time in uWSGI web-server logs seems fast for my application (6ms in avg) but I have HTTP 499 errors in 10 out of 1'000 requests and HTTP 502 errors in 4 out of 10'000 requests (The application have around two hundreds requests per second).

According to [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/768155/is-it-normal-to-have-http-499-errors-in-1-out-of-4000-requests) its seems typical to have 499 errors because the client closed connection  (**Question 1:** Is it really typical in real applications?). how about 502 errors? is it typical in real applications?(**Question 2**)

I guessed that requests queued in NGINX and waiting for Python response so they exceeded NGINX time limit. But seems it's not a true because everytime I test server using Google Chrome network analyzer I got the response (200) fast using a usual network bandwidth (60kbps). I test this by scripting load test.

[image: Network Analysis]

uWSGI Config:

```
[uwsgi]
http = 0.0.0.0:7000
wsgi-file = app.py
callable = app
processes = 12
lazy = true
lazy-apps = true
logto = /root/logs/data-gathering.log
```

NGINX Config(selected parts):

```
worker_connections 10000;
keepalive_timeout 65;
worker_rlimit_nofile 30000;
worker_processes auto;
```

The server load average is around 1.4 (with 4 CPU Core) and 70% of memory is still free.